# Cordova camera crashes app after taking picture

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to take photo from camera using cordova-plugin-camera and sometimes the camera app retrieves me the photo normally, but sometimes it crashes. How can I solve this?

I've followed the tutorial from this page: [clearlyinnovative](http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/ionic-framework-camera-image-uploads-and-base64-strings)

A little bit of my code:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(

    // Imagem obtida com sucesso, em imageURI
    function(resultImageUri) {

        // HERE - Sometimes the app crashes at this point, and sometimes it retrieves me the file normally...
    },

    // Error
    function(error) {
        console.error('navigator.camera.getPicture error - ', error);
    },

    {
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        quality: 40,
        targetWidth: 500,
        targetHeight: 500,
        allowEdit: true,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    }
);
```

Comment: Try with these options  `var options = {
      quality : 75, destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 300,
      targetHeight: 300,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    }`

Comment: refer this http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/